# Property 'exact' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RouteProps' Error in typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am getting an error like this while creating private routing in Typescript can anyone Help?

> Type '{ exact: true; render: (routerProps: RouterProps) => Element; }'
> is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RouteProps'.
> Property 'exact' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
> RouteProps'.

```js
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import { Route, Routes, RouterProps, useLocation, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";


interface RenderRouteProps extends RouterProps {}

const RenderRoute: React.FC<CustomRoute> = props => {
    const { component } = props;
    const Component: React.ComponentType<RenderRouteProps> = component!
    
    return (
        <Route exact render={(routerProps: RouterProps) => <Component {...routerProps} {...props} />}/>
    );
};

const PrivateRoute = (props: PrivateRouteProps & {redirectPath?: RouteRedirectProps, animate?: boolean}) => {
    const location = useLocation();
    const { appRoutes, redirectPath } = props;

    return (
        <Suspense>
            <Routes location={location}>
                {appRoutes.map((route, index) => (
                    <RenderRoute key={index} {...route} />
                ))}
                {redirectPath?.length && redirectPath.map((path, index) => (
                    path && <Navigate to={path.to} key={index} />
                ))}
            </Routes>
        </Suspense>
    )
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a props interface which extends `RouteComponentProps:`

```
 import { RouteComponentProps } from '@reach/router';

interface ISignupPageProps extends RouteComponentProps {
  someProp: string;
}

class SignupPage extends React.Component<ISignupPageProps> {
  // ...
}
```

or if the component doesn't have any props, use `RouteComponentProps` directly:

```
   class SignupPage extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps> {
  // ...
}
```

The type declaration includes `path` and some other potential props as optional, so it doesn't cause any errors if they're omitted. For reference, here's the type declaration (part of the above typings on DefinitelyTyped)

```
export type RouteComponentProps<TParams = {}> = Partial<TParams> & {
    path?: string;
    default?: boolean;
    location?: WindowLocation;
    navigate?: NavigateFn;
    uri?: string;
};
```

Try this hope it will solve your problem. For more information click [here](https://github.com/reach/router/issues/141)

Answer (score 0):

This error happens from upgrading the **'react'** package and relatively **'react-router'** package in the latest version (at the time of this answer 6.22.3).

Props in `<Route>` tag have been updated and some previous props like **'exact'** have been removed.

```
export declare function Route(_props: RouteProps): React.ReactElement | null;
export interface RouterProps {
    basename?: string;
    children?: React.ReactNode;
    location: Partial<Location> | string;
    navigationType?: NavigationType;
    navigator: Navigator;
    static?: boolean;
    future?: Partial<Pick<FutureConfig, "v7_relativeSplatPath">>;
}
```

If you look at the RouteProp declaration, there is no **exact** prop.

```
export declare function Outlet(props: OutletProps): React.ReactElement | null;
export interface PathRouteProps {
    caseSensitive?: NonIndexRouteObject["caseSensitive"];
    path?: NonIndexRouteObject["path"];
    id?: NonIndexRouteObject["id"];
    lazy?: LazyRouteFunction<NonIndexRouteObject>;
    loader?: NonIndexRouteObject["loader"];
    action?: NonIndexRouteObject["action"];
    hasErrorBoundary?: NonIndexRouteObject["hasErrorBoundary"];
    shouldRevalidate?: NonIndexRouteObject["shouldRevalidate"];
    handle?: NonIndexRouteObject["handle"];
    index?: false;
    children?: React.ReactNode;
    element?: React.ReactNode | null;
    hydrateFallbackElement?: React.ReactNode | null;
    errorElement?: React.ReactNode | null;
    Component?: React.ComponentType | null;
    HydrateFallback?: React.ComponentType | null;
    ErrorBoundary?: React.ComponentType | null;
}
export interface LayoutRouteProps extends PathRouteProps {
}
export interface IndexRouteProps {
    caseSensitive?: IndexRouteObject["caseSensitive"];
    path?: IndexRouteObject["path"];
    id?: IndexRouteObject["id"];
    lazy?: LazyRouteFunction<IndexRouteObject>;
    loader?: IndexRouteObject["loader"];
    action?: IndexRouteObject["action"];
    hasErrorBoundary?: IndexRouteObject["hasErrorBoundary"];
    shouldRevalidate?: IndexRouteObject["shouldRevalidate"];
    handle?: IndexRouteObject["handle"];
    index: true;
    children?: undefined;
    element?: React.ReactNode | null;
    hydrateFallbackElement?: React.ReactNode | null;
    errorElement?: React.ReactNode | null;
    Component?: React.ComponentType | null;
    HydrateFallback?: React.ComponentType | null;
    ErrorBoundary?: React.ComponentType | null;
}
export type RouteProps = PathRouteProps | LayoutRouteProps | IndexRouteProps;
```

As @Pawan suggested, this prop can be safely removed and get this working.